# When I deploy the asp.net application on Sharepoint 2013 getting the exception as conditionally APTCA assembly not enabled in current AppDomain

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013, system.web.extensions

Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjaxv45.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_ScriptResourceMapping()' failed.

Assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is a conditionally APTCA assembly which is not enabled in the current AppDomain.  To enable this assembly to be used by partial trust or security transparent code, please add assembly name 'System.Web.Extensions, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B5FC90E7027F67871E773A8FDE8938C81DD402BA65B9201D60593E96C492651E889CC13F1415EBB53FAC1131AE0BD333C5EE6021672D9718EA31A8AEBD0DA0072F25D87DBA6FC90FFD598ED4DA35E44C398C454307E8E33B8426143DAEC9F596836F97C8F74750E5975C64E2189F45DEF46B2A2B1247ADC3652BF5C308055DA9' to the the PartialTrustVisibleAssemblies list when creating the AppDomain.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjaxv45.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_ScriptResourceMapping()' failed.

Assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is a conditionally APTCA assembly which is not enabled in the current AppDomain.  To enable this assembly to be used by partial trust or security transparent code, please add assembly name 'System.Web.Extensions, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B5FC90E7027F67871E773A8FDE8938C81DD402BA65B9201D60593E96C492651E889CC13F1415EBB53FAC1131AE0BD333C5EE6021672D9718EA31A8AEBD0DA0072F25D87DBA6FC90FFD598ED4DA35E44C398C454307E8E33B8426143DAEC9F596836F97C8F74750E5975C64E2189F45DEF46B2A2B1247ADC3652BF5C308055DA9' to the the PartialTrustVisibleAssemblies list when creating the AppDomain.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjaxv45.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_ScriptResourceMapping()' failed.

Assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is a conditionally APTCA assembly which is not enabled in the current AppDomain.  To enable this assembly to be used by partial trust or security transparent code, please add assembly name 'System.Web.Extensions, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B5FC90E7027F67871E773A8FDE8938C81DD402BA65B9201D60593E96C492651E889CC13F1415EBB53FAC1131AE0BD333C5EE6021672D9718EA31A8AEBD0DA0072F25D87DBA6FC90FFD598ED4DA35E44C398C454307E8E33B8426143DAEC9F596836F97C8F74750E5975C64E2189F45DEF46B2A2B1247ADC3652BF5C308055DA9' to the the PartialTrustVisibleAssemblies list when creating the AppDomain.]
   Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjaxv45.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +27

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjaxv45.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjaxv45.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_ScriptResourceMapping()' failed.

Assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is a conditionally APTCA assembly which is not enabled in the current AppDomain.  To enable this assembly to be used by partial trust or security transparent code, please add assembly name 'System.Web.Extensions, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B5FC90E7027F67871E773A8FDE8938C81DD402BA65B9201D60593E96C492651E889CC13F1415EBB53FAC1131AE0BD333C5EE6021672D9718EA31A8AEBD0DA0072F25D87DBA6FC90FFD598ED4DA35E44C398C454307E8E33B8426143DAEC9F596836F97C8F74750E5975C64E2189F45DEF46B2A2B1247ADC3652BF5C308055DA9' to the the PartialTrustVisibleAssemblies list when creating the AppDomain..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +973
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +150
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +236
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +139
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1005

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjaxv45.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjaxv45.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_ScriptResourceMapping()' failed.

Assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is a conditionally APTCA assembly which is not enabled in the current AppDomain.  To enable this assembly to be used by partial trust or security transparent code, please add assembly name 'System.Web.Extensions, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B5FC90E7027F67871E773A8FDE8938C81DD402BA65B9201D60593E96C492651E889CC13F1415EBB53FAC1131AE0BD333C5EE6021672D9718EA31A8AEBD0DA0072F25D87DBA6FC90FFD598ED4DA35E44C398C454307E8E33B8426143DAEC9F596836F97C8F74750E5975C64E2189F45DEF46B2A2B1247ADC3652BF5C308055DA9' to the the PartialTrustVisibleAssemblies list when creating the AppDomain..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +646
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this by removing the all the local referenced assemblies. and add the assembly reference from global, for which are used in the code.
and removed all the additional assembly references which are not really using in the code.